# How do I compute the following integral with splitting the domain?

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have problems in computing the following integral $$\int_\Bbb{R} \int_\Bbb{R} |f(x,y)| dx dy$$ where $$f:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}; (x,y)\mapsto \frac{1}{x^2}\,\,\text{if}\,\,0<y<x<1,(x,y)\mapsto -\frac{1}{y^2}\,\,\text{if}\,\, 0<x<y<1, (x,y)\mapsto 0,\,\,\,\text{else}$$

I first wanted to fix my $y$ and then split the inner integral into $$\int_0^y\frac{1}{y^2}dx+\int_y^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx=...\frac{2}{y}-1$$ then I wanted to integrate over $y$, i.e. $\int_0^1 \frac{2}{y}-1 dy$ but this doesen't give me $1$. So I think id should give one as a result but I don't see the error.

Can someone maybe help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two triangular regions, one in the unit square below the diagonal where $|f|=1/x^2$ and one in the unit square above the diagonal where $|f|=1/y^2$:
$$
\int_0^1 dx \int_0^x dy |f| + \int_0^1 dy \int_0^y dx |f|
=
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2} \int_0^x dy + \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{y^2} \int_0^y dx 
=
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x} + \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{y} = \infty+\infty=\infty.
$$
Alternatively
$$
\int_0^1 dy \int_0^1 dx |f| 
=
\int_0^1 dy [\int_0^y dx |f|+\int_y^1 dx |f|]
=
\int_0^1 dy [\int_0^y dx \frac{1}{y^2}+\int_y^1 dx \frac{1}{x^2}]
=
\int_0^1 dy [y \frac{1}{y^2}+ \frac{-1}{x}\mid_y^1]
=
\int_0^1 dy [\frac{1}{y}+ [-1-\frac{-1}{y}]
=-1+2\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{y}=-1+2\times \infty = \infty
$$

Comment: Sorry why do you integrate one time  $dydx$ and then in the other summand $dxdy$  As I said our TA told us that we should get 1.

Comment: This is an 2D integral over two separate triangles, and the order of integration is chosen different because this leads to simple expressions. The values over the first and second triangle are both infinite, so the total integral is also infinite. [I fail to see why that integral is supposed to yield 1.]

Comment: One gets a different result if $|f|$ is replaced  by $f$ in the integral kernel. I suspect that is an error in the TA.